# Spring and CAS using Proxy Tickets

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

I have two web applications, Webapp A and webapp B. Webapp A is Spring 3.1 webapp. Webapp B is separate non-spring webapp. Both are protected by CAS. My goal is to allow webapp A to use a proxy ticket to retrieve information from webapp B.

To simplify things I've taken the cas-sample provided by spring-security to be webapp A. The default sample configured to use my local cas works as expected. For those unfamiliar with the cas-sample, it provides an example that uses a proxy ticket to request another page within the cas-sample application. I then use a simple page under an apache webserver protected using mod_auth_cas for webapp B. Again, webapp B works as expected. When I change the cas-sample to request webappB using a proxy ticket it does not work. The response from the request for webappB is the CAS login page. Note: I've tried an tomcat webapp (non-spring) for webapp B, with same result. Which leads me to believe the problem is not in webapp B. Below is the code used to make the request to webapp B using the proxy ticket. And the security context configuration can be viewed [here](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-security/samples/cas/sample/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml?r=11dc3363cc57433e0583c01304232bb8a6c5c45c).

```
final String targetUrl = "https://server/webappB";
final CasAuthenticationToken token = (CasAuthenticationToken) request.getUserPrincipal();
final String proxyTicket = token.getAssertion().getPrincipal().getProxyTicketFor(targetUrl);
final String serviceUrl = targetUrl+"?ticket="+URLEncoder.encode(proxyTicket, "UTF-8");
String proxyResponse = CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(serviceUrl, "UTF-8");
```

What am I doing wrong? Why would this work when the above targetUrl is within webapp A but not an external application?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**: If it helps here is what appears in the CAS log when a request is made to the webapp A page that uses the proxy ticket.

```
[org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Attempting to retrieve ticket [TGT-2-YX0RNVRDHAPyGLy6ymGGVucUSQyjtre4jvGrAxYk2hXsehsxqx-cas]
[org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Ticket [TGT-2-YX0RNVRDHAPyGLy6ymGGVucUSQyjtre4jvGrAxYk2hXsehsxqx-cas] found in registry.
[org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Added ticket [ST-3-JrQKqqpZJz00a2hsGZP6-cas] to registry.
[org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - Granted proxy ticket [ST-3-JrQKqqpZJz00a2hsGZP6-cas] for service [https://server/webappB] for user [testUser]
[org.jasig.cas.web.support.CasArgumentExtractor] - Extractor generated service for: https://server/webappB
[org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Attempting to retrieve ticket [ST-3-JrQKqqpZJz00a2hsGZP6-cas]
[org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Ticket [ST-3-JrQKqqpZJz00a2hsGZP6-cas] found in registry.
[org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Removing ticket [ST-3-JrQKqqpZJz00a2hsGZP6-cas] from registry
[org.jasig.cas.web.support.CasArgumentExtractor] - Extractor generated service for: https://server/webappB
[org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction] - Placing service in FlowScope: https://server/webappB
[org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction] - Placing service in FlowScope: https://server/webappB
[org.jasig.cas.web.support.CasArgumentExtractor] - Extractor generated service for: https://server/webappB
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured this one out. I was wrong the problem did lie in webapp B. Apparently proxy authentication is not supported by mod_auth_cas. I was able to get the desired results with my alternate webapp B (which was a simple Java webapp with tomcat). This webapp was using a CAS filter defined in the web.xml. The reason this wasn't working initially is that the validateUrl parameter was not set to proxyValidate and the authorizedProxy parameter was not set. After setting these parameters correctly webapp B was able to accept proxy tickets. Here is what the final filter configuration looks like:

```
   <filter>
     <filter-name>CAS Filter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.CASFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.loginUrl</param-name>
         <param-value>https://cas.server:9443/cas/login</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.validateUrl</param-name>
         <param-value>https://cas.server:9443/cas/proxyValidate</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.authorizedProxy</param-name>
         <param-value>https://webappA:8443/cas-sample/j_spring_cas_security_proxyreceptor</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.serverName</param-name>
         <param-value>webappB:7443</param-value>
     </init-param>
   </filter>
```