# How to call an external rest api authenticated by the same CAS SSO

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

I have a microservice that is protected by cas sso. There is also another microservice that is also authenticated by the same cas server. In my app I need to call a rest api from the second microservice. I've searched alot and just found a few about it, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838545/spring-and-cas-using-proxy-tickets). I agve it a try as follows:

```
final String targetUrl = "https://server/webappB";
final CasAuthenticationToken token = (CasAuthenticationToken) request.getUserPrincipal();
final String proxyTicket = token.getAssertion().getPrincipal().getProxyTicketFor(targetUrl);
final String serviceUrl = targetUrl+"?ticket="+URLEncoder.encode(proxyTicket, "UTF-8");
String proxyResponse = CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(serviceUrl, "UTF-8");
```

but the `proxyTicket` is `null`! What I must to do (probably in my client app cas settings) to get it working?

p.s. I'm new to sso and don't know if this is the only way to call an external rest api or not. I get manually the `JSESSIONID` cookie of the external rest service from `firefox` and somehow set it in a request in my app code and could to get response but have no idea how I can do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make calls to the other service's API do you need to make the request as the logged-in user? Typically service to service calls use a machine token and not a user token. If the user context is required you could look at minting JWTs as service tickets:

https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.0.x/installation/JWT-Authentication.html

You could pass the JWT to the other service's API to provide user context but I would recommend using a different form of authentication as it would allow anyone with a valid JWT to call your service's API.

Answer (score 0):

I like [@creamstout10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988780/creamstout10) answer, I think it is the way to go although I have been using the CAS Protocol proxy tickets approach for service to service calls with older versions of CAS.

You don't specify which CAS client you are using. In all cases, if you don't get a proxy ticket usually you need to configure the proxy receptor URL correctly, so that CAS server can call it (to confirm, check CAS server logs for errors). For example, if you are using java cas client directly, check ***proxyReceptorUrl*** property here:

https://github.com/apereo/java-cas-client#orgapereocasclientvalidationcas20proxyreceivingticketvalidationfilter

If using spring-security-cas you should check that module's documentation for settings those properties in Spring config.